# Are there good third party EDMX generator/updater tools out there?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, edmx

Are there good third party EDMX generator/updater tools out there?
The visual studio EDMX is driving nuts. I constantly have to restart VS2008 in order to get the EDMX to properly update.
Are there any tools out there people like?

This is somewhat subjective but I figured it would be ok to ask nonetheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I know about for now is the [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/). They offer great value for Linq-to-SQL (ability to update model etc.), but for EF, it's probably a bit less compelling. But check them out! Worth a look.

Comment: Thanks. I did find that one. Like you said for EF, it is indeed not that useful.

Comment: Sadly, this product is [discontinued as of 31 December 2013](http://forum.huagati.com/topic210-product-to-be-discontinued-on-31-dec-2013.aspx?MessageID=755#post755). No new licences will be issued.